# Не перехватывает исключение DoesNotExist и ObjectDoesNotExist в django python

Tags: python, django

Подключаю класс через `importlib` и пытаюсь перехватить исключение через `DoesNotExist` и `ObjectDoesNotExist`, не работает, выводит ошибку `Clients matching query does not exist.`

**view**

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
uuid = 'someUuid'
modelPath = 'clients.models'
imp_model = importlib.import_module(modelPath)
cls_model = getattr(imp_model, 'Clients')
try:
   cls2 = cls_model.objects.get(Q(related_uuid__icontains=uuid))
except ObjectDoesNotExist: # тоже самое с cls2.DoesNotExist:
   print 'No exist'
```

**model**

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, verbose_name='Имя')
    related_uuid = models.JSONField(blank=True) # json dict
```

комбинация с `cls2.DoesNotExist`, тоже выдает такую же ошибку. Возможно дело в том, что я импортирую класс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно перехватывать исключение, указанное в классе модели

```
try:
   cls2 = cls_model.objects.get(Q(related_uuid__icontains=uuid))
except cls_model.DoesNotExist:
   print 'No exist'
```

Вариант с  `cls2.DoesNotExist` не сработает, потому что cls2 не будет содержать нужного объекта

Comment: дополнил ответ.